# changing javascript to for loop to run faster .but not working

Tags: javascript

old javascript:

```
<script>
var tags1 = {!jsonDescriptionData1};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete1]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags1, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
var tags2 = {!jsonDescriptionData2};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete2]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags2, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
var tags3 = {!jsonDescriptionData3};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete3]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags3, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
var tags4 = {!jsonDescriptionData4};
$("input[id$=autocomplete4]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags4, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
var tags5 = {!jsonDescriptionData5};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete5]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags5, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
var tags6 = {!jsonDescriptionData6};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete6]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags6, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
var tags7 = {!jsonDescriptionData7};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete7]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags7, function(item){
              return matcher.test(item);
          }) );
      }
});
var tags8 = {!jsonDescriptionData8};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete8]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags8, function(item){
              return matcher.test(item);
          }) );
      }
});
var tags9 = {!jsonDescriptionData9};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete9]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags9, function(item){
              return matcher.test(item);
          }) );
      }
});
var tags10 = {!jsonDescriptionData10};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete10]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags10, function(item){
              return matcher.test(item);
          }) );
      }
});
</script>
```

New javascript with loop:

```
<script>
integer j;
for(j=0;j<10;j++){
var tags[j] = {!jsonDescriptionData[j]};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete[j]]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags[j], function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
}
</script>
```

This is some thing wrong in my new javascript that is why it is not working .can some correct my code .is it possible to write this kind of code .

thanks in advance

Comment: What error you get? as i i know {!value} is not correct javascript structure.

Comment: `{!foo}` is not valid JavaScript. Are you sure your code worked to begin with? Did you forget to expand some template before posting?

Comment: This code is regarding Auto completion but it is not working

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: From my controller i have get data to UI {!XXXX}

Comment: How do you expect this to play along with the JavaScript loop?

Comment: According to you if your old javascript works you should concatenate value and number whic is at the end with + "j" . Hope this works you cant use as array value of j like [j].

Comment: Can you suggest any other way

Comment: <script>
var j;
for(j=0;j<10;j++){
var tags + "j" = {!jsonDescriptionData+ "j"};
$( "input[id$=autocomplete + "j"]" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags + "j", function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
}
</script>

Try this code. Not sure but it's shouuld work

Comment: No @Naitik, it's still not going to work. But if you're going to post an answer post it as an answer and not as a comment.

Comment: Yes @MattiVirkkunen I agree with you.